# Gradient is too blurred in Chart.js Line Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I have created a line chart with a color gradient in Chart.js, however the color seem to blur together so much, I can't differentiate between them.

It's supposed to look like this:

[image: distinct colors]

But it ends up looking like this:

[image: blurred colors]

I created a gradient that is applied to the canvas chart inside my JavaScript. I'm not sure whether it is because I don't have enough color values or because my chart is stretched out.

Could someone assist me in solving this?

Here is my JS for creating the gradient:

```
// Create gradient
grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(170.000, 600.000, 150.000, 0.000);

// Add colors
grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.200, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.400, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.600, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.800, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(1.000, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg2k82rp/) for my current chart.

Comment: try to add these stops:`grd.addColorStop(0.001, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.201, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.401, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.601, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.801, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the wrong start and end coordinates when you create the linear gradient.

This documentation may help you understand better what the coordinates should be set to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient

Change both `x` coordinates to 0, to get straight horizontal lines. Then, decrease the start `y` and increase the end `y` to make the start and end colors more visible.

**Code:**

```
grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0.000, 350.000, 0.000, 100.000);
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: gradient]

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xg2k82rp/3/

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. I'll look into if it's possible to get the colors to be separated better.